# Add another site to my flask application on the same server

Tags: python, flask, configuration

So I currently have `sitea.com` setup and has been actively running for over a year. Now I want to add `siteb.com`, `siteb.com` will also have a blog on it, called `siteb.com/blog`

Can someone please help me?

Here is my current configs:
`app.py`:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
        '''
        home() will show the homepage of my website sitea.com
        '''
        return render_template('index.html')
```

The thing is both `sitea.com` and `siteb.com` are pointed at the same server, so if I try to access each one, it will pull it up only the existing `sitea.com` site, but i want to make it based on domain name via flask.

How can I do this? I'd assume a change for the existing `sitea.com` in the flask config would be needed, along with another change for `siteb.com` to be added.

Can anyone assist me?

Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what tools like Apache and nginx were made for

Comment: @JoranBeasley - can two sites have exactly this same block? location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

Comment: you might want to post a new Apache question, or really I would recommend nginx

Comment: Im using nginx, is that block possible without causing difficulty?

Comment: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html#virtual-hosting

Answer (score 0):

One possible thing can be, you split your site url and render in different domain. like:

```
@app.route('/')
      def home():
         # Return different results depending on the host
         url = split_url(request.url)
         if "www.sitea.com" == url['domain']:
             return "<h1>You are visiting sitea.com</h1><p>Here's your URL " +
     request.url + "</p>"
         else:
             return "<h1>You are not visiting www.sitea.com</h1><p>Here's your URL "
     + request.url + "</p>"

    def split_url(url):
         "Returns the full URL in two parts, the domain, and the path"
         url = url.split('/', 3)
         return {'domain': url[2], 'path': url[3]}
```

Comment: anyway to specify the route like `@app.route('sitea.com')` ?